# Can we load Excel file in Office.js Add-in

Tags: office-js

I am trying to load a Excel file in Excel online.

By loading a file I mean lets say I receive an Excel file from a service which I need to show on the current workbook.

The file location can be a url or any folder in my site.

```js
Excel.run(function (context) {
 var workbook = context.workbook;
 //workbook.load or something ?
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to provide more info about what you're trying to accomplish?  for example:  In your scenario, what triggers the loading of the file?  i.e., does the user click a button in the add-in's task pane (within Excel) to trigger the opening of the new file?  Do you want to open the file in the same window where the task pane is displayed?  Or, perhaps there's not going to be a task pane at all (i.e., you're simply wanting to import some data into Excel)?

Comment: Kim Brandi The trigger would be a button(present in add-in's task pane) click.
This would open the excel document already downloaded by a service in say a directory in my site's any virtual directory, in the currently active workbook.
i hope i am sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add-ins are scoped to the document and are intended to extend the functionality of the Office application, not as a mechanism for opening documents themselves.

What you're describing is what [WOPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh622722%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is intended for. The `WOPI` protocol provides an interface between Office and the document storage.

While you can implement your own `WOPI` client, it isn't a trivial process. A far simpler approach is to leverage the user's OneDrive via [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph). Files stored in OneDrive include a [webUrl](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem#properties) property. If you open this URL it will automatically open the file in the correct application (Excel, Word, etc).

Comment: Marc i was able to hook up to one-drive and get the weburl of the document saved there, now how can i load that excel document in currently open workbook. Assume the existing workbook to be empty.
or do i need to just launch the url from javascript and the existing session will automatically open it in excel online.?

Comment: The `webUrl` will open the file in Excel Online. Office Online works differently, there isn't a concept of an "open but unsaved" document so if you're looking at a blank Excel Online, you're technically looked at a saved but empty document on OneDrive.

Comment: Marc Sorry for the delay in responding to this thread I was busy with other task.
 But Thanks for the explanation. i will give it a try.

Comment: Marc I was able to hookup the addin with the Onedrive and use the weburl property to launch in excel online.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to open an workbook through a link/path, that is not possible yet in the web add-ins as the scope of the add-in is limited to the workbook. It is something in our roadmap to support cross workbook scenario. If you are looking to embed the workbook in a browser, Marc's response has the answer (works for OneDrive, SharePoint only).