# Online Edit office Files in my platform

Tags: office-js, office365api

I want to view/edit office files (doc/excel/ppt) in my platform (online).
Is there any office Api reference or Sdk or any iframe or any service that ms office provides ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we load Excel file in Office.js Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791384/can-we-load-excel-file-in-office-js-add-in)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you have a web application and you'd like users to be able to open and edit Office documents inside your application. There is no API for doing this. Perhaps you could try opening [Office Online](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx?s=1&auth=1&nf=1) in an iFrame. But users would have to login and manually open the document.

Answer (score 1):

The full answer to your question will largely depend on the specifics of what you're trying to achieve, but I'd suggest that you start by exploring the capabilities of [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/).

Using the Microsoft Graph API, for example, you could [upload an Excel file to OneDrive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_put_content) and then subsequently [retrieve](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get) that `DriveItem`, and use the value of the `webUrl` property (i.e., a URL) in the **Get DriveItem** response to access/open that file in Excel Online.