# Loading Project Workbook Directly from Project Add-In Panel

Tags: office-addins, ms-project

We are creating an add-in app for Microsoft Project that the user will operate from the side panel.

We have 2 workbooks that are included as part of the app experience. Currently, we are requiring the user to download the books and then open them manually. We are attempting to have the user be able to click a link and load the books in question directly in Project without having to download and manually open them.

From our research (e.g. [Can we load Excel file in Office.js Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791384/can-we-load-excel-file-in-office-js-add-in)), it seems as if this is not doable. Can anyone confirm if that is true or not? And if it is possible, point us in the right direction for how we can go about accomplishing this.

Thanks much for any help you can offer..

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely read from an Excel file into MS Project:

First, create a connection:

```
Public Function GetConnection(filename As String) As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ConnStringBuilder As New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder

    'Build the connection string    
    ConnStringBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

    'Need the full path string to your Excel file 
    ConnStringBuilder.DataSource = "[full path and filename goes here]"

    'Need this part to work with Excel, note that it assumes you have a header row
    ConnStringBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES")
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnStringBuilder.ConnectionString)

    ConnStringBuilder = Nothing
    Return MyConnection

End Function
```

Once you have the connection, you can use TableAdapters to treat Excel sheets like database tables. Note that this only works well for reads. You can write to Excel, but the Jet engine (ACE.OLEDB.12.0) does not support Delete directly (at least that I have been able to find).

There's a lot to learning how to use TableAdapters. This might give you some clues on where to get started:

[Read and Write Excel Documents Using OLEDB](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB)

Comment: Thanks Eric. Unfortunately we need to use Javascript, not VB, but I guess it sounds like what we're looking to do may perhaps be possible, even if we can't just directly load the file in question.

Comment: Why Javascript? If you're building an Office Add-in, the natural language choices are either C# or VB.net.

Comment: We are developing a Task Pane Addin that uses office.js APIs for interaction with Project.

Comment: Why use office.js APIs when you can build a VSTO add-in?