# Open an Excel Online Workbook from an Add In

Tags: excel, office-js

I am developing an excel add in that reads a data source, generates an excel file and stores the file in OneDrive for the currently logged in user. All of this is working fine.

At the end of that process, I want to load the new workbook in the window that I already have open with Excel Online. Is there any way to do this?

I can't seem to find an API call to open a new workbook.

Comment: Maybe [Can we load Excel file in Office.js Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791384/can-we-load-excel-file-in-office-js-add-in) may assist.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new worksheet from from the [base64 encoded workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks#create-a-workbook). This method is currently only available in the beta version of office.js. Use this script to use the beta. https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
    var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    sheets.addFromBase64(
        base64String,
        null, // get all the worksheets
        Excel.WorksheetPositionType.after, // insert them after the worksheet specified by the next parameter
        sheets.getActiveWorksheet() // insert them after the active worksheet
    );

    return context.sync();
});
```